# How to edit WinPE dual-boot boot image?

Tags: windows, winpe

I had Windows 10 both x86, x64 ISO. I used this to creat Windows AIO USB installer for Windows 7, 8.1, 10.

Now I have a working AIO installer and do not know how to edit WinPE Boot manager to edit the name from Windows 10 setup (x64) to Microsoft Windows Setup (x64).

I know it is possible to have both x86 and x64 in one install.wim image but I want it to be on two separate install.wim.

I am attaching the boot manager snapshot.
[image]

Comment: Follow the instructions in the WDT Toolkit to make one image and just add the install.iso for both x86 and x64. You can add as many install images you want but consider your media limitations.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48595

Here's a blog for deploying Dual-Boot WinPE images and they go over manipulating the BCD tables using bcdedit.
http://deploymentresearch.com/Research/Post/324/Creating-a-dual-boot-WinPE-5-0-boot-image-x86-and-x64-support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two separate questions.

**First question** is about editing boot menu display names. These names are stored in BCD file (\boot\BCD for BIOS, \EFI\Microsoft\boot\BCD for UEFI) on USB drive in your case.

You can use for example [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net/) to edit "Description" element of corresponding loader and also view complete BCD contents. To load any BCD just copy it (in Explorer) and then paste on Visual BCD Editor desktop icon.

**Second question** is about creating separate .wim files from a common wim - just extract first part, then second part using dism.exe (extract, then make new wim).

You would have to edit BCD for "Application Device" of loader to reflect changed name/path of .wim file(second install.wim). Application Device" and "OS Device" have to include full path to .wim file. Also edit corresponding device element addressed by GUID if necessary (you should place install.wim and boot.sdi in same directory for best results).

Huh, not very trivial is editing boot loader for .wim file!

Comment: The first part was answer to my question. I already have two wims under x86 x64 and boot manager point to them. I needed to edit the BCD description. Thank you for your time.